# Wordpress - Ultimate Product Catalog Plugin - What file lists the products?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ultimate Product Catalog **Plugin**.

What is the file that handles the html for the products to list?
Like when i get the short code what file in the plugin handles the HTML that is suppose to be listed out when that short code is put into the page, I want to edit the html and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the file `Functions/Shortcodes.php`

When shortcode `[product-catalog]` is used, the big function `Insert_Product_Catalog()` in this php file will put together the HTML for display.

Comment: let me look please give me a few mins

Comment: How to overwrite the **ultimate-product-catalog plugin** Functions/Shortcodes.php in my chid-theme any possiblity?